# Adding sounds to the onClick event in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, frontend

Excuse me for poor English as this is my first question here, Basically I am trying to add sounds to buttons via an onClick event but not sure where I went wrong, a fresh pair of eyes/explanation would help tremendously! Here is my html:

`````
````<button onClick="handleClick()" class="w drum">w</button>
<button onClick="handleClick()" class="a drum">a</button>
<button onClick="handleClick()" class="s drum">s</button>
<button onClick="handleClick()" class="d drum">d</button>
<button onClick="handleClick()" class="j drum">j</button>
<button onClick="handleClick()" class="k drum">k</button>
<button onClick="handleClick()" class="l drum">l</button`
`````

JS

```
function handleClick() { 

 var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;

switch (buttonInnerHTML) {
case "w":
    var tom1 = new Audio("tom-1.mp3");
tom1.play();
    break;

case "a":
    var tom2 = new Audio("tom-2.mp3");
tom2.play();
    break;

case "s":
    var tom3 = new Audio("tom-3.mp3");
tom3.play();
    break;

case "d":
    var tom4 = new Audio("tom-4.mp3");
tom4.play();
    break;

case "j":
    var crash = new Audio("crash.mp3");
crash.play();
    break;      

    case "k":
    var kick = new Audio("kick.mp3");
kick.play();
    break;      

    case "l":
    var snare = new Audio("snare.mp3");
snare.play();
    break;  


default:                


} 

}
```

Comment: Your usage of an inline event handler will not change what `this` points to.  That's the core of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the content of the clicked button the right way. You can pass the event to the function and use it as follows:

```
var buttonInnerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
```

Example:

```js
function handleClick(event) { 
     var buttonInnerHTML = event.target.innerHTML;
     console.log(buttonInnerHTML);
}
```

```html
<button onClick="handleClick(event)" class="w drum">w</button>
<button onClick="handleClick(event)" class="a drum">a</button>
<button onClick="handleClick(event)" class="s drum">s</button>
<button onClick="handleClick(event)" class="d drum">d</button>
<button onClick="handleClick(event)" class="j drum">j</button>
<button onClick="handleClick(event)" class="k drum">k</button>
<button onClick="handleClick(event)" class="l drum">l</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier way to do this is to avoid all of those inline events by getting the buttons (after the DOM is loaded) and adding listeners to each. Also, get rid of switch statement by creating an object with `key => value` pairs.

```js
let audios = {
    w: 'tom-1.mp3',
    a: 'tom-2.mp3',
    s: 'tom-3.mp3',
    d: 'tom-4.mp3',
    j: 'crash.mp3',
    k: 'kick.mp3',
    l: 'snare.mp3'
};
// If you don't want audios to play at the same time, define the variable here
let audio = new Audio();

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Function to handle clicks
    let handleClick = function(e) {
        let value = e.target.innerText;
        console.log(audios[value]);
        // If you want audios to play at the same time,
        // uncomment next line and delete the below one
        // let audio = new Audio(audios[value]);
        audio = new Audio(audios[value]);
        audio.play();
    };
    // Get elements with drum class
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.drum');
    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    });
});
```

```html
<button class="w drum">w</button>
<button class="a drum">a</button>
<button class="s drum">s</button>
<button class="d drum">d</button>
<button class="j drum">j</button>
<button class="k drum">k</button>
<button class="l drum">l</button>
```

With this approach, you can even generate all buttons from Javascript:

```js
let audios = {
    w: 'tom-1.mp3',
    a: 'tom-2.mp3',
    s: 'tom-3.mp3',
    d: 'tom-4.mp3',
    j: 'crash.mp3',
    k: 'kick.mp3',
    l: 'snare.mp3'
};
// If you don't want audios to play at the same time, define the variable here
let audio = new Audio();

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Function to handle clicks
    let handleClick = function(e) {
        let value = e.target.innerText;
        console.log(audios[value]);
        // If you want audios to play at the same time,
        // uncomment next line and delete the below one
        // let audio = new Audio(audios[value]);
        audio = new Audio(audios[value]);
        audio.play();
    };
    let container = document.querySelector('#button-container');
    for(let i in audios) {
        let btn = document.createElement('button');
        btn.className = `${i} drum`;
        btn.innerText = i;
        btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
        container.appendChild(btn);
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="button-container"></div>
```